# Which phase of compilation is responsible for detecting undeclared structs?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

For instance if i had the following code

```
int f()
{
 /*set struct value*/
 struct test_2 t;
 t.j = 0;
}
```

If i get an error such as `struct test_2` not declared i was wondering which phase of the compilation detects this particular error? Also i was wondering which phase compilation would remove the comment from the code? I am sorry if it's silly question i am just studying little bit about compilers and was curious.

As far as i know compilation phases include the following

```
Lexical Analysis
Parsing
Semantic Analysis
Intermediate Code Generation
Code Optimization
Final Code Generation
```

Comment: This question is likely to be closed for being too broad (there are two questions in here, and the answer to at least one of them is "it depends"). If you can focus the question, please do.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe i agree it can vary but i just wanted a general answer to get an idea. I think scott's answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the compiler, but the most natural fits would be Lexical Analysis for the comments (since they're ignored by the rest of the process and are regular expressions), and Semantic Analysis for detecting that something hadn't been declared (since Parsing wouldn't keep a symbol table).